# Find the largest size file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

See more: PowerShell How to get the largest size file from the list of the files using PowerShell

I have the path `C:\temp`. I want to find the largest size file from the `C:\temp` folder.

Answer (score 9):

```
Get-ChildItem c:\temp | Sort Length -desc | Select-Object -first 1
```

Comment: I sense a pattern in this user's latest questions ;-). Maybe he doesn't know about `gci`, `sort` and `select` ...